# How to install NPM / elasticsearch-head without Internet connection?

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, node.js, elasticsearch

I am trying to install NPM on my machine without any Internet connection. Through some research on the Web I have come across suggestions to use [npmbox](https://github.com/arei/npmbox). So I gave npmbox a try but when I try to `bin/npmunbox /path/to/npm.npmbox` (npm.npmbox being the offline package of NPM) to install NPM into my machine, there is an error:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

**Why do I need NPM?**

The overall problem is that I am trying to install [elasticsearch-head](https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) into the machine and there is a `package.json` file which requires `npm install` to install and also `npm run start` to get the interface to run. Thus my question.

**Some additional information you may want**

OS => RHEL6

ELK Stack Version => 5.5.0 (can't install elasticsearch-head as a plugin, deprecated)

Can someone help me with *any* of the 2 problems I have? Any additional information that you need can be provided to you. Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am *very* new to NPM so if I missed out any obvious solutions please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: You have installed node as well as NPM, right?

Comment: In addition it's likely that the install will download further files and (node) modules.

Comment: @Burgi both node and NPM are on my machine with Internet connection.. however, I am trying to install these on a machine with no Internet connection and I do not know how to go about doing that.

Comment: @Seth as long as I am able to install NPM or even activate elasticsearch-head offline, I do not mind downloading further files and modules as long as the process can be done offline completely (e.g no `curl`)

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest [portable node.js](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nodejsportable/). It has the following features:

- Runs a NodeJS instance in a command line shell.
- Includes the Node Package Manager (NPM).
- Completely portable - runs off a USB, SD or hard drive.
- Does not require administrator privileges.
- No need for any external software - simply download extract and run!
- Packaged in PortableApps.com format for easy integration.

To upgrade npm, use the following process:

- Download an [NPM release tar](https://github.com/npm/cli/releases)
- Extract the NPM tar into the global `node_modules` folder as `npm_new`
- Rename the existing `npm` folder to `npm_old`
- Rename the `npm_new` folder to `npm`

**References**

- [node.js - How to manage npm install in a system without internet connection - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33658801/how-to-manage-npm-install-in-a-system-without-internet-connection)
- [Node js Stand Alone Portable with NPM - Cody Swartz - Programmer · Web Developer · Gamer](https://codyswartz.us/wp/finds/node-js-stand-alone-portable-with-npm)